# How do I get the month displayed in the context in table calendar

Tags: flutter, dart, android-calendar

In a flutter app that I'm building, I want to retrieve the month currently being displayed in the table calendar i.e. a variable which should store the name of month being displayed in the form of a string.

For example when days-dates of March are being displayed, the variable should store "March" when the user swipes on the calendar to see the days-dates of April, the variable should update to "April". This is my code as of now :

```
TableCalendar(
                firstDay: DateTime.utc(1950, 01, 01),
                lastDay: DateTime.utc(2050, 01, 01),
                focusedDay: DateTime.now(),
                calendarFormat: CalendarFormat.month,
                startingDayOfWeek: StartingDayOfWeek.monday,
                headerStyle: HeaderStyle(
                  formatButtonVisible: false,
                ),
              ),
```

link to the calendar package used: https://pub.flutter-io.cn/packages/table_calendar/versions/3.0.0-nullsafety.1

In a similar query, someone suggested to used *focusedDay* but I'm unsure how that'll help. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you add some code of what you currently have?

Comment: @nvoigt i've edited the post for your ref

Answer (score 2):

you can get the month using `onPageChanged`, like this

```
TableCalendar(
   ...
   onPageChanged: (d) {
      print(d.month.toString());
   },
   ...
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the first and last visible day from the event `onVisibleDaysChanged`.

You can get a month name from a `DateTime` by using the `DateFormat` class.

Example:

```
TableCalendar(
            firstDay: DateTime.utc(1950, 01, 01),
            lastDay: DateTime.utc(2050, 01, 01),
            focusedDay: DateTime.now(),
            calendarFormat: CalendarFormat.month,
            startingDayOfWeek: StartingDayOfWeek.monday,
            headerStyle: HeaderStyle(
              formatButtonVisible: false,
            ),
            onVisibleDaysChanged: (first, last) {
               print(DateFormat.LLLL().format(first));
               print(DateFormat.LLLL().format(last));
               // you could write those values into a variable here
               // maybe call setState if that variable is part of your state
            }
          ),
```

Comment: onVisibledaysChanged is showing error because it's not a part of the package i'm using, instead, it has onPageChanged which does not take such params

Comment: Okay, that is weird, maybe we are talking about different packages? It should have it, see [their git repo](https://github.com/aleksanderwozniak/table_calendar/blob/5721feea4e555af6a8ab6d75f373fba173cd27f1/lib/src/calendar.dart#L97).

Comment: yeah the package is diff, i've already mentioned the package, you may have a look at that

Comment: If that is not the package you are using, you need to update your link. Your link in the question is where I got this information.

Comment: the link takes you to prelease version right ? the 3.0.0-nullsafety one, it's the same

Comment: You are right, it was removed. I guess you will have to ask the author why that was and what to do instead.